# In java, how do I make a loop that finishes while the answer is a whole number?

Tags: java, android

I am new to java and couldn't find an answer to this question.

I am trying to make the loop until the first number divided by the second number is equal to two numbers

```
int number1;
int number2;
Random randomizer = new Random()

do {
    Number1 = randomizer.nextInt(10) + 1;
    Number2 = randomizer.nextInt(10) + 1;
while ("Check if Number1 / Number2 is equal to a whole number")
```

Comment: `while (number1 % number2 == 0)`.

Comment: *"...until the first number divided by the second number is equal to two numbers"* What does "is equal to two numbers" mean? How does that relate to the title of the question?

Comment: _until the first number divided by the second number is equal to two numbers._ Explain "equal to two numbers".

Comment: I dont really think you have to know java to know this, seems like a homework assignment

Answer (score 5):

The [remainder operator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/opsummary.html) returns the remainder when dividing the first operand by the second operand. If first/second is a whole number:

```
first % second == 0
```

So make your check:

```
while (number1 % number2 == 0)
```